springdoc generates wrong maxLength value
I have a problem with org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:jar:1.6.0
I have a schema definition with maxLength: 255 in my OpenAPI descripition. When I start my app and view the generated docs, the maxLength value has changed to 2147483647
    ids:
      name: ids
      in: query
      description: 'uuid'
      required: true
      schema:
        type: array
        maximum: 0
        maxItems: 100
        items:
          type: string
          maxLength: 255

When i start my app and open link localhost:8082/swagger-ui.html, i have this schema with the wrong value:
          {
            "name": "ids",
            "in": "query",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "maxItems": 100,
              "minItems": 0,
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "maxLength": 2147483647,
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }

How can I fix this problem?
